# P-values heatmap - Representation of all pairwise comparisons/p-values with R (e.g. like a colored correlation matrix)

Tags: r, plot, statistics, correlation, p-value

I have **a lot of pairwise comparisons**; it is very **difficult to visualize or add all the p values ​​in a report**. I was wondering if there was a function in R that could **represent well the pairwise comparisons/all the p values.**

Something like this :

[image]

But **instead of having the values of the correlation** in the small squares **we would have the p values?**

Thank you

******* **EDITED/SOLUTION** *********

Solution (thanks to @Park) when using emmeans package for pairwise comparisons :

```
p.val.test<-pwpm(emmeans(your_model, "your_factor"),means = FALSE, flip = TRUE,reverse = TRUE) # p-values presented compactly in matrix form
p.val.test<-sub("[<>]", "", p.val.test)
p.matx<-matrix(as.numeric((p.val.test)),nrow = length(p.val.test[,1]),ncol = length(p.val.test[,1])) #if your factor has 5 levels ncol and nrow=5
rownames(p.matx) <- colnames(p.matx) <-colnames(p.val.test)
p.matx[upper.tri(p.matx, diag=FALSE)] <- NA
melt(p.matx) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value))
```

Comment: Which test did you fit to get p values?

Comment: @Park I fitted a linear mixed model (with lmer), then used Anova (from Car) then I used a Tukey post-hoc test to have the pairwise comparisons (using function emmeans)

Comment: You can use `geom_tile`from `ggplot2`to recreate this heatmap with p-values but it all depends on how you store the values. What does your dataset of p-values look like ?

Comment: Group1-Group2 pvalue=0.04. next line Groupe1-group3 p.value=0.0001, next line Group1-group4 p.value=0.15....... I have 30 lines...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I made matrix formed pairwise simple linear regression.

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(1,2,3,4),
  x2 = c(1,0,3,4),
  x3 = c(1,0,7,4),
  x4 = c(1,0,7,-1),
  x5 = c(8,0,7,-1)
)
colNames <- names(dummy)
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- combn(colNames, 2, function(x) summary(lm(dummy[x][,1] ~ dummy[x][,2]))$coefficients[2,4])

mat <- round(mat,2)
rownames(mat) = colnames(mat) = colnames(dummy)
mat

     x1   x2   x3   x4 x5
x1   NA   NA   NA   NA NA
x2 0.15   NA   NA   NA NA
x3 0.35 0.19   NA   NA NA
x4 0.96 0.80 0.27   NA NA
x5 0.45 0.88 0.75 0.33 NA
```

Then, use `melt` and `geom_tile()`(or `geom_rect` , etc) will return correlation matrix plot style p-value matrix plot

```
melt(mat) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value))
```

[image: pval?]

Comment: Thank you @Park. It works ! Last question, how can I color (in red for exemple) p-value<0.05 in the result plot? t

Comment: @learneRS `+scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "")` will make fill low as red. You might have to add specific options to see red only `p.value<0.05`

Comment: An error is shown using `high=""`   "Error: Unknown colour name: " . What worked was to use `scale_fill_gradient2(mid ="red", limit = c(0,0.05),name="p-value")` to only color in red the p-values<0.05 and all p-values>0.05 are in grey

Comment: @learneRS I left `high` blank because it can be customized. Congrats :D